# Nginx - how to correctly limit access to the subdirectories?

Tags: nginx

I have two locations in Nginx config:

/api/*

and

/api/currencies/for_banki_ru/v1/*

I need to close access to the /api/* and open access for all for the /api/currencies/for_banki_ru/v1/* .

Now in my config I have

```
location ~* ^/api/    
    {   

      allow *************** - here IP;         
      deny all; 
***********************
```

And

```
location ~* ^/api/currencies/for_banki_ru/v1/
    {   
      allow all; 
***************
```

As result /api/ - closed, but /api/currencies/for_banki_ru/v1/ closed too - in Nginx log has errors:

```
6760#7308: *235126 access forbidden by rule, client: **********, server: **********, request: "GET /api/currencies/for_banki_ru/v1/index.php HTTP/1.1"
```

How to open access to the /api/currencies/for_banki_ru/v1/* ?

Comment: Why do you use regex locations?

Comment: For paths like /api/***/***/***/***.php

Comment: Well, nginx uses **first** matching location, so reorder them.

Comment: I already have to try make config with first location ~* ^/api/    and second location ^~ /api/currencies/for_banki_ru/v1/ in my config file, but it's not solved me problem.

Comment: Already tryed... Not solved...

Comment: In that case, show **full** config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by moving needed API to another URL/dir.